# Класс для работы с БД из Java

Tags: java, mysql

Добрый день! Пытаюсь локализовать все функции, связанные с работой с БД в одном классе. Например, пытаюсь написать функцию, которая на вход получает строку с текстом запроса, а возвращает результат.

```
public Map ReadToMySQL(String query) {
    try {
        // opening database connection to MySQL server
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // getting Statement object to execute query
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // executing SELECT query
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int count = rs.getInt(1);
            ....
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
        try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    }
    return ....;
}
```

Вопрос в том, что должна возвращать такая функция? Предполагается, что запрос к БД может быть любым: возвращать разное количество переменных и переменные разных типов. Очень не хочется писать для каждого запроса свою функцию чтения из базы. Может быть есть какая-то стандартная архитектура класса для работы с БД?

Comment: А почему не хочется писать для каждого запроса свою функцию чтения из базы? Так все и делают ведь

Comment: Технология преобразования данных из реляционной БД называется [Object-Relational Mapping](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM). Тема слишком обширная чтобы можно было дать однозначный ответ. Решение сильно зависит от Вашей конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите получить ответ на запрос в виде `List<Map<String, String>>`, а на вход подаете только запрос в виде строки, то у Вас явно не правильно спроектированная архитектура приложения.

Входными параметрами должны быть параметры запроса, а не сам запрос.
И каждый метод должен выполнять только свое предназначение, а не всю логику работы с базой.
Тем самым Вы разделяете логику приложения от логики БД.
Результатом выполнения метода, должен быть или какой-то примитив или Ваш объект(ы).

Если Вам сказали так сделать, к примеру специальная задача в универе, то это другое дело.
А если Вы сами так решили, то не стоит делать так, как делать не надо.

Делайте правильно...

```
class MyObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public DBClassName(String url, String user, String password) {
    // Init driver here
}

public void connect() {
    // Connect to DB
}

public List<MyObject> getAllData() throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table")) {
        final List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            final MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            obj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            result.add(obj);
        }
        return result;
    }

}

public MyObject getDataByID(int id) throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?")) {
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            final MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            obj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            return obj;
        } else {
            // not found logic here
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. и никогда не делайте так, как показал в примере пользователь Senior Pomidor.
В приведенном им примере, Ваше приложение будет потреблять МНОГО памяти, так как ни один PreparedStatement не закрыт.
Ни один generic не параметризирован.

Comment: 1) получим ошибку, если id - BigInteger. 
2) класс MyObject  подходит только для таблицы вида id, Name. в впросе говорится. что разные таблицы могут быть

Comment: Под каждую таблицу и входящие параметры должен быть свой метод. Это если писать правильно.

Answer (score 1):

предлагаю 2 готовых варианта:

1) если мы хотим получить значение конкретных столбцов

2) все хотим получить

```
public class DataBase {

    public String user = "root";
    public String password = "root";
    public String connectionString = "localhost:3306";

    private Connection connection;

    private final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private int dbConnectionTimeOut = 10000;

    public DataBase() {

    }

    public DataBase(String dbUser, String dbPassword, String connectionHost, int dbConnectionTimeOut) {
        user = dbUser;
        password = dbPassword;
        connectionString = connectionHost;
        this.dbConnectionTimeOut = dbConnectionTimeOut;
    }

    public String[] getArrayFromDB(String table, String[] args) {
        return getArrayFromDB(table, args, "");
    }

    /**
     *  класс возвращает нам массив из наших столбцов, который мы указали 
     * @param table name of table
     * @param args columns
     * @param where
     * @return
     */
    public String[] getArrayFromDB(String table, String[] args, String where) {
        String[] result = new String[args.length];
        String query = "SELECT ";
        for (String arg : args)
            query += arg + ", ";
        query = query.substring(0, query.length() - 2) + " FROM " + table;
        if (!where.equals(""))
            query = query + " WHERE " + where;
        query = query + ";";
        ResultSet resultSet = getResultSet(query);
        try {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                    result[i] = resultSet.getString(args[i]);
            } else
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                    result[i] = "null";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    // возвращает все данные  в виде ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>
    public ArrayList getEntities(String table){
        String baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        ArrayList entities = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            entities = (ArrayList)
                    loadObjectFromResultSet(getResultSet(baseQuery));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  entities;
    }

    public Object loadObjectFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < columnCount -1 ; i++) {
                String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                Object objectValue = resultSet.getObject(i);
                map.put(columnName, objectValue);
            }
            objectArrayList.add(map); // после того, как всю строку считали, сохраняем в массив и заново 
        }
        return objectArrayList;
    }


    public void connect() {
        try {
            // Create MySQL Connection
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            // https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/mysql-error-java-sql-sqlexception.html 0000-00-00 date exception
            setConnection(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + connectionString + "?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", user, password));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet(String sqlQuery) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
```

результат

```
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    db.connect();
    ArrayList entities = db.getEntities("schema.address");
    System.out.println(entities.size());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае может подойти ассоциативный массив, либо массив ассоциативных массивов, если за одно обращение планируется делать выборку из нескольких таблиц. Если точно известна структура БД, то ключом Map'a будет строка, а значением - Object

Answer (score 0):

Если нет ограничений на использование сторонних библиотек, то рекомендую использовать Spring Framework. Там есть намного более удобные механизмы работы с БД, чем те, которые используете вы. [Тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) неплохо изложено, как это делается.

Answer (score -1):

Вчера вот сделал из урока реализацию ввода через консоль в БД MySQL и поиска по имени пользователя и вывод всей строки. 
Код расписывать не стану. Там правда выполнено в виде void-метода, но думаю разберёшься.

[Вот ссылка.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9r11UfyquwoXy1TVnlDZkdGZTA/view?usp=sharing)